# Shell script executes but does not register change to path

Tags: bash

I'm just trying to change this path with a simple shell script. If I type in the commands one by one it works no problem. If I put it in a shell script and run it it runs fine with no errors but does not alter the path.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=~/Library/Python/3.4/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bash_profile
```

What am I doing wrong here?

If I double click on the file the output is...

```
    /Users/Parthenon/Desktop/ShellScripts/changeawsebpath ; exit;
Philips-MBP:~ Parthenon$ /Users/Parthenon/Desktop/ShellScripts/changeawsebpath ; exit;
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: How are you running the script and where are you expecting `PATH` to be changed?  A script cannot alter its parent's environment, you must `source` for that to happen

Answer (score -2):

The =~ is an conditional BRE operator vs an assignment

Comment: That only applies inside conditionals. (As an aside, the `=~` operator supports (platform-dialect) *E*REs.)

Comment: ...and not just inside conditionals in general, but *specifically* inside `[[ ]]`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point; additionally, `=~` would only be recognized as an operator _if surrounded by whitespace_.